# How to save child entity with symfony 2 FosRestBundle and Angular Resource

Tags: angularjs, symfony, angularjs-resource

I'm having some troubles with FOSRestBundle and Angularjs Resource.

In my Symfony App I have two entity :

```
class Museum
{

    private $id;
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EV\CityBundle\Entity\City")
    */
    private $city;


     // ... Getter and Setteer
  }




class City
{

    private $id;
    private $name;

    // ... Getter and Setteer
}
```

And I have one form with :

```
$builder->add('name');

$builder->add('price');


$builder->add('city', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'EVCityBundle:City',
            'property' => 'name');
```

So, my form is waiting for someting like this :

```
array(
    name => "Museum of science",
    price => "4",
    city => 1234
);
```

And it's work very well in my Symfony App

I use JMSSerializerBundle to configure what data I want to expose in my API.

So in my Angular App, I get my data with Angularjs Resource and I get en object like this  :

```
{
   name: "Museum of science",
   price: "4",
   city: { "id" : 1234, "name": "France" }
}
```

And, when I want to save it, I use :

```
museum.name = "Museum of Super science";
museum.city.id = 1337;
museum.city.name = "Lyon"; 
museum.$save()
```

And the data send over the POST request is :

```
{
   name: "Museum of science edited",
   price: "5",
   city: { "id" : 1337, "name": "Lyon" }
}
```

But since my form is waiting for a { city : id } I'm not able to save the new city id.

I can do that :

```
$request->request->set('city', $request->request->get('city')[id]);
```

but it's ugly and i'll be hard to manage in my application because I have a lot of entity with sub entity.

So, my question is : There is a way to automatically re-map the data correctly ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution ! I can use JMSSerializer to deserializer my Json to an object, ans JMS Serializer automatically load correctly entity and sub-entity if the id is set in the JSON.

```
$data = json_encode($request->request->all());
$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
$activity = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'EV\MyBundle\Entity\Museum', 'json');
```

But you must add this in your config.yml :

```
services:
    jms_serializer.object_constructor:
        alias: jms_serializer.doctrine_object_constructor
        public: false
```

This solution work perfectly. Hope i'll help someone.